# Mutate by group based on a conditional

Tags: r, dplyr

I am trying to add a summary column to a dataframe. Although the summary statistic should be *applied* to every column, the statistic itself should only be calculated based on conditional rows.

As an example, given this dataframe:

```
x <- data.frame(usernum=rep(c(1,2,3,4),each=3),
                final=rep(c(TRUE,TRUE,FALSE,FALSE)),
                time=1:12)
```

I would like to add a `usernum.mean` column, but where the mean is only calculated when `final=TRUE`. I have tried:

```
library(tidyverse)

x %>% 
  group_by(usernum) %>%
  mutate(user.mean = mean(x$time[x$final==TRUE]))
```

but this gives an overall mean, rather than by user. I have also tried:

```
x %>% 
  group_by(usernum) %>%
  filter(final==TRUE) %>% 
  mutate(user.mean = mean(time))
```

but this only returns the filtered dataframe:

```
# A tibble: 6 x 4
# Groups:   usernum [4]
  usernum final  time user.mean
    <dbl> <lgl> <int>     <dbl>
1       1 TRUE      1       1.5
2       1 TRUE      2       1.5
3       2 TRUE      5       5.5
4       2 TRUE      6       5.5
5       3 TRUE      9       9  
6       4 TRUE     10      10
```

How can I apply those means to every original row?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If we use `x$` after the `group_by`, it returns the entire column instead of only the values in that particular group.  Second, `TRUE/FALSE` is logical vector, so we don't need `==`

```
library(dplyr)
x %>%
     group_by(usernum) %>% 
     mutate(user.mean = mean(time[final]))
```

---

The one option where we can use `$` is with `.data`

```
x %>% 
    group_by(usernum) %>%
    mutate(user.mean = mean(.data$time[.data$final]))
```

Comment: A bit less elegant: `merge(x, aggregate(time ~ usernum, x[x$final,], mean), by = "usernum")`